# How to enforce a minimum password length in Jenkins?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

As part of our audit the users have to set passwords with certain length.

Under Jenkins --> `Configure Global Security` --> I can enable security and select `Jenkins own user database`.  But I haven't found a way to set the rules for password.

Is there any plugin that could help?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is not to do this directly in Jenkins.

Use an external source for authentication (and authorisation) such as an [LDAP](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin), where you can properly enforce password quality policies in a centralised manner, avoiding the operational overhead of maintaining different databases of users and passwords.

Comment: Although that is the best pracrise, it doesn't answer the question OP raised.